# Can you get an iphone app to read from a file like an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I am making an application that i want to populate a huge array, I want the information in my array to be objects, with information from my file. So if there is a way to read/write to a file, does not have to be a excel file, how would I go about doing this, or is NSCoding the only way?

Comment: CSV? XML? JSON? Excel? SQlite? **Pick one** based on requirements. *Then* look at how to implement it (and what libraries are available to do so). This is "not a real question" at this point, unless it can be refined more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read/write files. Check out [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There is no reason why you can't read from an excel file, but for the sake of efficiency and simplicity it would be much better if you read from a CSV or JSON file.